# Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList<MyVariable>

Tags: java, arraylist, casting, warnings, unchecked-cast

Here is a part of a program that sends an ArrayList from a server to a client. I want to remove the warning about the last line in this code:

Client code:

```
Socket s;
(...)
// A server is sending a list from the other side of the link.
ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
MyList = (ArrayList<MyVariable>) ois.readObject();
```

MyVariable is a Java class with some attributes. The server is creating an ArrayList and filling it with MyVariable variables as items. Then it sends the complete list to the client.

I would like to know why do I have a warning there and how to code perfectly in order to have 0 warnings. If it is possible I would like to avoid using "@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")". ;)

Thank you,

Luis

Comment: Send an array over the socket instead of a Collection.  `(MyVariable[]) ois.readObject()` is a safe cast.  To convert a Collection to a typed array, use `list.toArray(new MyVariable[0])`.  To convert an array to a Collection, use the `Arrays.asList` method.

Answer (score 23):

Try this

```
Object obj = ois.readObject();
// Check it's an ArrayList
if (obj instanceof ArrayList<?>) {
  // Get the List.
  ArrayList<?> al = (ArrayList<?>) obj;
  if (al.size() > 0) {
    // Iterate.
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
      // Still not enough for a type.
      Object o = al.get(i);
      if (o instanceof MyVariable) {
        // Here we go!
        MyVariable v = (MyVariable) o;
        // use v.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

It's impossible to avoid this warning. `readObject()` returns an Object. You need to cast it. And casting to a generic type will always generate such a warning.

If you want to make your code as clean as possible, which is a good idea, you should respect the Java naming conventions though, and make variable names start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can. Does my answer miss anything?

Comment: It doesn't return a `List<MyVariable>`, and is overkill. The OP should know that a `List<MyVariable>` is what is sent.

Answer (score 4):

I was running into a similar problem as OP and found a good solution with a combination of comment from @VGR and Java 1.8 method for Arrays.

I will provide my answer in terms of OP's question, so it is generic and hopefully helps others:

1. Instead of returning a collection (list), return an array from the server. Covert collection to an array using the following on the server side code:

   `myVariableList.toArray(new MyVariable[0]);`

   If performance is an issue with above, following could be used, so that array does not need to be resized:

   `myVariableList.toArray(myVariableList.size());`
2. On client side convert array of object, to an array of MyVariable class.

   > This is specific to JAVA 8.

   `MyVariable[] myVarArr = Arrays.stream(ois.readObject()).toArray(MyVariable[]::new);`
3. Then, finally convert Array to a Collection (list).

   `List<MyVariable> myList = Arrays.asList(myVarArr);`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like that, but you can have a container (sort of an alias or typedef):

```
// add "implements Serializable" in your case
private static class MyVariableList {
    public List<MyVariable> value;
}
```

And work with `MyVariableList` instead. That way you explicitly provide enough information to the compiler to do type checking in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into a similar situation and was able to solve it.
My solution, applied to the example of the OP is this:

```
myList = (ArrayList<Someclass>) Arrays.asList( (Someclass[]) ois.readObject() );
```

I have changed the naming-conventions (like suggested by someone, already) to standard Java (objects start with lowercase-characters) and I have renamed the Class `MyVariable` to `Someclass` to make it explicit, that this really applies to any class (and not just Variables). I'm also assuming, that the corresponding object to `myList` on the server-side of type `ArrayList<Someclass>` has been written to the stream as an Array `Someclass[]`. Note, that this is easily done and analogous to the first part of what abhishek already suggested, but my solution differs on the last step insofar as:

1. I'm avoiding to call `Arrays.stream`
2. It's easier to read and quickly perceived as a simple (without further logic) and `checked` (not generating a warning) cast.