# deserialise file, then store content in ArrayList<String>. (java)

Tags: java, arraylist, deserialization, fileinputstream, objectinputstream

Assume serialise.bin is a file that is full of words and was an ArrayList when it was serialised

```
public static ArrayList<String> deserialise(){
    ArrayList<String> words= new ArrayList<String>();
    File serial = new File("serialise.bin");
    try(ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(serial))){ 
        System.out.println(in.readObject());   //prints out the content
    //I want to store the content in to an ArrayList<String>
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }
return words;
}
```

I want to be able to deserialise the "serialise.bin" file and store the content in an ArrayList

Comment: What's your question? Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: Don't return `ArrayList`. Instead, return `List` so callers of `deserialise` don't become depending on that implementation detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast it to `ArrayList<String>`, as `in.readObject()` does return an `Object`, and assign it to `words`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static ArrayList<String> deserialise() {

    // Do not create a new ArrayList, you get
    // it from "readObject()", otherwise you just
    // overwrite it.
    ArrayList<String> words = null;
    File serial = new File("serialise.bin");

    try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(serial))) { 
        // Cast from "Object" to "ArrayList<String>", mandatory
        words = (ArrayList<String>) in.readObject();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return words;
}
```

The annotation `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` can be added to suppress a type-safety warning. It occurs, because you have to cast an `Object` to a **generic** type. With Java's **type erasure** there is no way of knowing for the compiler, if the cast is type-safe at runtime. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275623/type-safety-unchecked-cast-from-object-to-arraylistmyvariable) is another post on this. Moreover `e.getMessage();` does nothing, print it or use `e.printStackTrace();` instead.

Comment: thanks for the help, it works but I have to add a "@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")". I am unsure what this does but once it has been added I no longer get a warning about "Type safety: Unchecked cast from object to ArrayList<String>"

Comment: You are right and you cannot avoid this warning, just suppress it. Updated the answer.

Comment: Is @SupressWarnings("unchecked") good code? In this case I would keep it in as I can think of another way.

Comment: You should **never** suppress a warning if you **can avoid it**, because it is there for a reason. However, in some cases like this it is impossible, so it is completely justified to do this.